# Socket.IO on Subdomain vhost and proxy

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-proxy, vhosts, http-proxy-middleware

I'm trying to proxy `socket.example.com:4000` to a websocket server `mydomain.com:3000` but the client can also connect to the server through `*.example.com:4000`, It's like `vhost` has no effect and the proxy configuration is set globally. I don't want other subdomains be proxied.

i use [vhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhost) and [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

```js
const options = {
    target: 'http://example.com:3000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true
};
    
const wsProxy = createProxyMiddleware(options);

app.use(vhost('socket.example.com', wsProxy));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need vhost nor http-proxy-middleware. i used [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) and some vanilla javascript.

```js
import httpProxy from 'http-proxy';

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: {
        host: 'example.com',
        port: 4001
    }
});

server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
    const domain = req.headers.host;
    const host = domain.split(':')[0];

    if (host === 'socket.example.com') {
        proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
    } else {
        socket.destroy();
    }
});
```

##Update##
Running on the same server without proxy or dedicated websocket server.

```js
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
    allowRequest: (req, fn) => {
        const domain = req.headers.host;
        const host = domain.split(':')[0];

        fn(null, host === `socket.example.com`);
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```